# How can I create a calculated column in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, calculated-columns

I am working on a basic data analysis project. The data being used is COVID-19 cases in a given US county.

[As you can see in this picture, there is a 'cases' column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld33Y.png)
The 'cases' column appears to be cumulative, as in every cell is concerned with the total number of cases that have occured on and up to the date the cell is associated with.

I would like to create a column that calculates only the number of new cases per day. I imagine it working something like this:

new_case(2022-05-13) = cases(2022-05-13) - cases(2022-05-12)

How would I go about making this calculated column in pandas or some other Python package?

I have not attempted this on my own.

Comment: use pandas `diff` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question so as to share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).  To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could use window functions for calculate the new cases occurrence

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2022-05-12', '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16'],
        'cases': [100, 120, 140, 160, 180]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

window = 1
df['new_cases'] = df['cases'].diff(periods=window).fillna(df['cases'])
print(df)
```